# Given $y=\frac{3+sin(2x)}{2+cos(2x)}$ find the equation of the tangent

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given the function $y=\frac{3+\sin(2x)}{2+\cos(2x)}$ find an equation of the tangent C at the point C such that $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I calculated the derivative ($\frac{6+\sin(2x)+4\cos(2x)+2}{(2+\cos(2x))^2}$), substituted $x$ with $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and got the slope of $-2$. The equation of the tangent hence has the form of $y=-2x+m$. What I should do to find the $m$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\xi$ be the value of the function at $\pi/2$; then $(x,y)$ lies on the tangent line through $(\pi/2, \xi)$ iff $y - \xi = -2(x-\pi/2)$, which is equivalent to $y = -2x + \xi + \pi$.